# Как сделать фильтр js/jq

Tags: javascript, jquery, фильтр

У меня есть несколько `checkbox`. У каждого элемента есть несколько `data-*`.
При активации любого `checkbox`  к элементам, не имеющим заданный `data-*`, применяется стиль css(прозрачность). Нужно чтобы при активации последующих `checkbox` стиль применялся только к тем элементам, которые были "задействованы" в  предыдущих `checkbox` (а значит имеют data-* уже активированного чекбокса)
Каждый `checkbox` меняет стиль у элемента с определенным `data-*`.

Пример:

1. `checkbox 1` *(меняет элементы без `data-name=egg`)* ***активирован*** 
   Все элементы не имеющие `data-name=egg` становятся полупрозрачными.
2. `checkbox 2` (*меняет элементы без `data-type=eat`)* ***активирован вторым*** 
   Все элементы, не имеющие и `data-name=egg` и `data-type=eat` становятся полупрозрачными и.т.д
3. `checkbox 3` меняет элементы без data-crow=milk

---

подскажите пожалуйста хотя бы в каком направлении двигаться, искать информацию
может быть будет оптимальнее сделать фильтр без `data-*`

Comment: если не data - тогда нужен обьект с теми-же данными -- который лучше создать сразу -- а так обходить все checkbox и проверять ключи обьекта на соответствие.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

макет фильтр еды по составу инградиентов на jquery с генерацией элементов из обьекта данных

```js
$(function() {
  function c() {
    d.forEach(function(a, e) {
      f.every(function(a, c) {
        return !a[0].checked || !!~b.item[e].indexOf(b.checkbox[c])
      }) ? $(a).removeClass("hide") : $(a).addClass("hide")
    })
  }
  var b = {
      checkbox: ["egg", "eat", "milk"],
      item: [
        ["egg", "eat", "milk"],
        ["milk", "eat"],
        ["egg"],
        ["egg", "eat"]
      ]
    },
    f = $.map(b.checkbox, function(a) {
      var b = $("<input/>", {
        type: "checkbox",
        click: c
      });
      $("<label/>").append(b).append(a).appendTo(".tabs");
      return b
    }),
    d = $.map(b.item, function(a) {
      a = a.join(" ");
      return $("<div/>", {
        text: a
      }).appendTo(".tabs")
    })
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #D2691E;
}
.tabs div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  margin: 8px;
}
.tabs div.hide {
  opacity: .2;
}
 input{
   margin-top: 40px
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs"></div>
```

тот же фильтр, но на js без jquery, для элементов существующих на странице

```js
 window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   function b() {
     c.forEach(function(a, b) {
       e.every(function(a, c) {
         return !a.checked || !!~d.item[b].indexOf(d.checkbox[c])
       }) ? a.classList.remove("hide") : a.classList.add("hide")
     })
   }
   var d = {
       checkbox: ["egg", "eat", "milk"],
       item: [
         ["egg", "eat", "milk"],
         ["milk", "eat"],
         ["egg"],
         ["egg", "eat"]
       ]
     },
     e = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll(".tabs input"), function(a) {
       a.addEventListener("click", b, !1);
       return a
     }),
     c = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".tabs div"))
 });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #D2691E;
}
.tabs div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  margin: 8px;
}
.tabs div.hide {
  opacity: .2;
}
input {
  margin-top: 40px
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">egg</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">eat</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">milk</label>
  <div>egg eat milk</div>
  <div>milk eat</div>
  <div>egg</div>
  <div>egg eat</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

У JQuery есть селектор [not](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).
Можно отключать все `data-egg`, такие что не `data-milk` вот так:

```
$("*[data-egg='']:not(*[data-milk=''])")
```

[Демо](https://plnkr.co/edit/rj3gRdxyJtdN2jxd7r2R)